# Trouble on finding a class object in a array of classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, finder

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to understand how to handle the following code in order to retrieve a class objects with a specified `id`.

In my view file I have:

```
@records = Users.all # This returns an array (class)
```

In another file, a partial template, I would like to retrieve, for example, the user with `id` 1, but if I make this:

```
@records.find(1)
```

I get an `enumerator` (class) of all records:

```
<Enumerator: [<Users id: 1, ... ] >
```

**How can I find the user with `id` 1 (or other ids) "a là Ruby on Rails Way"?**

---

**UPDATE**

I use `@records = Users.all` in a view file because I aim to *minimize calls to the database* since I need to iterate almost over all records and check them existence. If I do for example:

```
some_hash.each { |key, value|
  put User.find(value)
}
```

and I go in the log file, I will see a lot of database requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though this is probably quite slow, and I suspect there are some less than optimal designs in the app you're working on (not judging, we've all been there), [Array#index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000236) seems to be what you're looking for:

```
@records[@records.index{|user| user.id == 1}]
```

**Edit**

Although if you need to do something for every user, and you need to access them by id quickly, I'd probably do something like this in your controller. Even if it's not really faster, it's much more readable (to me anyways):

```
@users_hash = {}
User.all.each{|user| @users_hash[user.id] = user}
```

Then in your views you can do:

```
@users_hash[id].username
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `User.scoped` instead of `User.all`. `#all` will *immediately* query the database and return an array, whereas `#scoped` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which you can chain further queries. In this case, the database won't be hit until you try and somehow inspect or enumerate the result

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will help. It sounds like you want to use ActiveRecord query methods (like `find`) without hitting the database - which is a flawed approach because ActiveRecord is a data store API

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're mistaken. `@records.find(1)` is returning an object of the class Enumerator (which is not the same as the class Enumerator itself).

The problem here is that, as you've noted, `@records` is an Array, not an ActiveRecord object, and `Array#find` ([inherited from `Enumerable#find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001484)--which, when not given a block, returns an object of class Enumerable) is not the same method as `ActiveRecord::Base#find` (i.e. `User#find`).

What you should do is, in your controller, pick out the one user record you want:

```
@user = User.find 1
```

...and then use `@user` directly in your template. Generally you should avoid doing ActiveRecord lookups (e.g. `find`) in your templates. That kind of logic should happen in your controller.

Comment: I updated the question so that it is more clear why I use '@records = Users.all' in my view files.

Answer (score 0):

Last time for such case I ended up doing like this:

```
@assignments = Assignment.find_by_sql(' ... ')

@assignments.find(id: 1).first
```